# Hibernate/JPA JPQL to wrong SQL when querying Map<String,String> field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

This is my Entity configuration

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Payment.findByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM Payment p JOIN p.additionalAuthData a " +
    "WHERE KEY(a) = 'email' AND VALUE(a) = ?1 AND (p.paymentType = 4 OR p.paymentType = 10)")
public class Payment {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "payment_type")
  private Integer paymentType;

  /** other properties, getters and setters */

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "additional_auth_data")
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "field")
  @Column(name = "data_value")
  private Map<String, String> additionalAuthData;
}
```

The NamedQuery findByEmail("test@example.com") generates the following SQL

```
select -- all fields ...
from payment payment0_ inner join additional_auth_data additional1_ on payment0_.id=additional1_.id
where
  additional1_.field='email' and (select additional1_.data_value from additional_auth_data additional1_ where payment0_.id=additional1_.id)='test@example.com' and (payment0_.payment_type=4 or payment0_.payment_type=10)
```

which is *wrong*: it may work if you have *only one* row but it blows up otherwise. H2 complains *Scalar subquery contains more than one row* and PostgreSQL *more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*. In fact, query's where condition compares a scalar value ('test@example.com') with a subquery.

The correct SQL should be:

```
 select -- all fields
 from payment payment0_ inner join additional_auth_data additional1_ on payment0_.id=additional1_.id
 where additional1_.field='payerEmail' and additional1_.data_value='test@example.com' and (payment0_.payment_type=4 or payment0_.payment_type=10)
```

Is the HSQL correct? Is there a way to instruct Hibernate to generates a clever, better SQL? Is this a Hibernate bug?

Note: Hibernate shipped with Spring Boot Starter 1.3.7.RELEASE

**Edit**:
Using an @Embeddable class

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "additional_auth_data", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "field")
@Column(name = "data_value")
private Set<AdditionalData> additionalAuthData;

 @Embeddable
 public static class AdditionalData {
    @Column(name = "field", nullable = false)
    private String field;
    @Column(name = "data_value")
    private String dataValue;

    protected AdditionalData() {
    }

    public AdditionalData(String field, String dataValue) {
        this.field = field;
        this.dataValue = dataValue;
    }
    /** Getters, setters; equals and hashCode on "field" */
}


 @NamedQuery(name = "Payment.findByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM Payment p JOIN p.additionalAuthData a " +
    "WHERE a.field = 'email' AND a.dataValue = ?1 AND (p.paymentType = 4 OR p.paymentType = 10)")
```

solves the problem, and the SQL is correct, but it looks just plain wrong, like shooting a fly with a bazooka...

Comment: The SQL you quote as correct is what I got using a different JPA provider. Looks like you should raise an improvement request on your provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generates correct SQL without value().
Use just `a=?1`
But I would expect is should generate it simple also with it.

Comment: Thanks, the simplest solution is usually the best. After many attempts, I haven't tried this one. I agree with you and @Neil that Hibernate is maybe behaving incorrectly, in this case.